# How to make a left join query in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

My models:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(BucketUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    resource_type = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    url = models.URLField()
    text = models.TextField()
class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(BucketUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=rating_choices, default='1')
```

The PostgreSQL Tables:

```
posts_post :
| id | url | resource_type | text | content_id | user_id |

ratings_rating :
| id | rating | content_id | user_id |
```

I want to get the contents of `posts_post` table along with the respective `rating` values from `ratings_rating` for the same `content_id` and a `user_id` which I'll receive from the GET request. I can get that easily by SQL query like:

```sql
SELECT p.*, r.rating FROM posts_post p LEFT JOIN ratings_rating r ON p.content_id = r.content_id AND r.user_id = 100; /* Assuming user_id received was 100 */
```

or i can even do this:

```sql
SELECT p.*, (SELECT r.rating FROM ratings_rating r WHERE r.content_id = p.content_id AND r.user_id = 100) AS rating FROM posts_post p;
```

But, I'm troubled about how to do the same through Django ORM queries based on the models. Or, if I need to create new models for this? What would be the Django way of doing it? I'm still new with Django models, and I know I can use the raw query for this but I want to know the better way and the acceptable way of doing this.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have a Content model too. If so, you can filter content based on id and then get post and rating from content object. See the docs example (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) for how to to this.